# Probability theory: find distribution of a 'random time'

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

**PROBLEM**

---

Let $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ be independent and identically $\text{Exp}(1/\lambda)$-distributed random variables. Let in addition $S_{0}=0$ and $S_{n}=X_{1}+\dots+X_{n}$. Set

\begin{align}
N = \max\{n\;\vert\; S_{n}\leq x\}.
\end{align}

$N$ is a **random time**, equal to the number of that random sample, when $S_{n}$ for the last time stays under $x$. Then show that $N\in\text{Po}(\lambda x)$.

---

Here I define the exponential probability density, $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$, as

\begin{align}
f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}} \quad 0\leq x,\\ 
0\quad \text{elsewhere}.
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}

I have been told that characteristic functions would facilitate solving this problem, however these have not been introduced yet and I do not want to "cheat"! So, inspired by some other post on this forum I began computing the probabiltiy mass function for $N$, i.e. $p_{N}(n)$, for different values of $n$. We realize that $N$ is discrete and that $N\in \{0,\dots,n\}$. For $n=0$ I obtain

\begin{align}
p_{N}(n=0) = \mathbb{P}(N=0) = \mathbb{P}(S_{1}>x) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\leq x) = 1 - (1-e^{-\lambda x}) = e^{-\lambda x}.
\end{align}

But if I try finding the probability mass function for $n=1$ I run into trouble,

\begin{align}
p_{N}(n=1) = \mathbb{P}(N=1) = \mathbb{P}(\{S_{1}\leq x\},\{S_{2}>x\}) = \dots
\end{align}

here I am unsure what to do, but I use the defintion of the conditional probabiltiy and obtain

\begin{align}
\dots = \mathbb{P}(\{S_{2}>x\}\;\vert\; \{S_{1}\leq x\})\mathbb{P}(\{S_{1}\leq x\}),
\end{align}

and from here I am not sure what to do. I can evaluate the second factor in the last equality, but the conditional probability I do not know how to obtain. The answer should be that $N\in\text{Po}(\lambda x)$, but how do I get to that (not using characteristic functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum $S_n$ can be viewed as the time of the $n$th arrival in a Poisson process $M_t$ with arrival rate $\lambda$. Observe that

$$\left\{N = n\right\} = \left\{S_n \leq x,\, S_{n+1} > x\right\} = \left\{M_x=n\right\},$$

and $M_x\sim Poisson\left(\lambda x\right)$ by the properties of the Poisson process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do you prove that this is a property of the Poisson process? If I can understand that step, then I would be satisfied, because of right now I have no pre-knowledge of random processes. And the problem assumes no knowledge of such are required.

Comment: By definition, a Poisson process is a counting process (all sample paths are increasing, take values in the positive integers, and never jump by more than $1$ at any time) which has "stationary and independent increments," which means that 1) the difference $M_t-M_s$ is independent of $M_{t'}-M_{s'}$ when the intervals $\left[s,t\right]$ and $\left[s',t'\right]$ are disjoint; and 2) the distribution of $M_t-M_s$ depends on $s$ and $t$ only through the difference $t-s$. If the process has these properties, $M_t$ _must_ be $Poisson\left(\lambda t\right)$, often shown using an ODE argument.

Comment: I should also add that, once you have shown that $M_t$ has these properties, it is then easy to show that the "interarrival times," i.e., the length of time between two consecutive jumps of the process, are i.i.d. exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$. One observes that $\left\{T_1 \geq t\right\} = \left\{N_t = 0\right\}$ and applies the Poisson pmf.